# Save image from media_root to Django Rest Serializer

Tags: django, image, serialization, django-rest-framework, httprequest

I am currently working on a project that allows mobile app user to upload images to a Django Server.

Here is my view that serves the POST request from the user:

***class ImageDetailsViewSet(APIView):***

```
def post(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            ######### Accept string from the user
            imgStr = request.data['image']

            media_filename = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'img.jpg')

            ######## Create decoded string to a JPEG file and save it to media_root
            img = Image.open(StringIO(imgStr.decode('base64')))
            img.save(media_filename, 'JPEG')

            ###### Update request data to include the newly created image to the request
            user = request.user.get_username()
            data1 = {'image': media_filename, 'category': 1, 'status': 'Y', 'user': user}

            serializer = ImageDetailsSerializer(data=data1)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        except:
            raise
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_415_BAD_REQUEST)
```

My ImageDetailsSerializer:

```
class ImageDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):  
    class Meta:
        model = ImageDetails
        fields= ('image','status','category', 'user')
```

The code always returns an HTTP 400 error which means that the serializer is not valid.

Here are the solutions I tried to apply but doesn't work in this case:

1. Change the media_filename from `data1 = {'image': media_filename, 'category': 1, 'status': 'Y', 'user': user}` to img but it returns `TypeError: <PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=2976x3968 at 0x841D2F0> is not JSON serializable` error
2. Replace media_filename to `media_url/img.jpg`, it returns the same error.
3. Update image field in the serializer by adding (see code below) but it does make any improvements at all:

   ```
      class ImageDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):   
          image = serializers.ImageField(use_url=True)
          class Meta:
               model = ImageDetails
               fields= ('image','status','category', 'user')
   ```

My questions are:

1. What should be stored in an ImageField of a serializer? an image, image URL or the directory of which the image is stored?
2. Is this the correct way/technique to save data from a remote user? Or are there any other effective way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

1. It's the path relative to the media_root
2. You can change `data1` to a copy of `request.data` and merge key "user" into the new dict

Comment: I have tried to edit the request.data itself by adding `request.data['image'] = media_filename`
`request.data['category'] = 1`
`request.data['status'] = 'Y'`
`request.data['user'] = user` then updated my request to `serializer = ImageDetailsSerializer(data=request.data)` but I am still having 400 error (the serializer is not valid).

Comment: I think you can add 'image' 'status' 'category' 'user' into post parameters from request. If it doesn't work, you can print the validation error's detail.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this problem is to use Django-extra-fields plugin. :D 
Read https://github.com/Hipo/drf-extra-fields for more details.